# how to automatically create field for subcollection firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection of comments for the posts in a comments collection. However, how do I create a field (please, refer to the image[image: here]) automatically?

I can create field manually from firestore console. But, I am not sure how to call it in the code. I cannot find it online. Without the field my subcollection document says:

```
This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots
```

I use `commentsRef().doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments).set({data})` to create a comment, but how would I create a 'blahblah' field for the doc in sub-collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine but you are trying to add field inside a collection which is not possible but just update your code to the following and it should work

```
commentsRef().doc(widget.post.postId).set({
  'field': 'blahblah'
}).then((value) {
  print('Document Updated');
});
```

Here is your result [image]

Comment: oh, ok! thank you! so just same as the adding data I call 'field'? I was overthinking it... let me try it now!

Comment: i can help you more if you can provide more information on what value you want to add or data incase of yours

Comment: just use name of your field in 'field' value and then add your data in the 'blahblah'

Comment: I just needed to create this bogus field, other data is all working! Thanks!